# Does the MS Health API Support CORS?

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm working on a web app that connects to the MS Health API.  I'm able to get my authorization code from the API but then when I execute the POST to get the authorization token I get a CORS error.

Does the service have CORS enabled?  If not, what approach should I be taking to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

After spending some time with the MS Health support team on email, they confirmed that the server is set-up to support CORS.  The problem is that if you call the Summaries end-point (http://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Summaries) without adding the time period to the end (.../Summaries/Daily) you'll get a CORS error.  It would of course be more helpful to get a different, more obvious error.